# Asynchronous module definition (AMD) with Angular.dart?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I am curious to know if its possible to have Asynchronous module definition with Angular.dart (or dart in general), if yes, then please share a sample code for such a single page application.

Comment: Something like deffered loading? https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-async.DeferredLibrary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AMD is made largely irrelevant by the fact that Dart comes with a complete module system that is built into the language. That is the purpose of the `import` statement.  Dart files are dynamically loaded in Dartium.  If you are using the darttojs transpiler, it will create a single large file. The solution to this is to use use the [DeferredLibrary class](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-async.DeferredLibrary) which will cause darttojs to create separate javascript files for each annotated `import`

See [Seth Ladd's blog post](http://blog.sethladd.com/2013/04/lazy-load-libraries-in-dart.html) for more details.